Nautilus crashes when opening folders containing .js or .json files. Update glib2?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. In the past week or so, Nautilus started crashing every time it tries to open a folder containing  a .js or .json file. If I create a new folder, I can open it, but if I add a .json file to that folder, I can't.
This problem seems to be related to this Nautilus issue, which recommends upgrading to glib2 version >= 2.78 (I currently have glib2 2.72.4). That version isn't available through Ubuntu's available repositories, and given the importance of glib2 to the system I'm wary of installing it manually.
What's the best way to address this issue? I've looked at my apt history and don't see any obvious previous upgrades that would have caused this.

This is a known bug. Have you tried the recommendations found here or here?

Yes I've set WaylandEnable=false, and upgrading my system didn't help

Did you try the commands to completely kill nautilus? If needed/you want to attempt it, you can use these steps - https://linuxier.com/how-to-install-glibc-on-ubuntu/ - to update glibc

Yep, completely killing Nautilus doesn't help either. I'm wary of installing an unsupported version of glib2 and potentially breaking my system. Surely that can't be the best option?

In principle, Ubuntu also maintains a "backports" repository, where newer libraries are packaged for an older Ubuntu version. Unfortunatelly, and especially considering this rather visible bug, the latest available of glib2 for Ubuntu 22.04 is, as you found out, 2.72.4. There is no more recent version in the backports.
Unfortunatelly, for the not-to-technical end-user, this means you may need to live with the bug for some time longer. Your options to resolve the issue are

Upgrade to 24.04, which is also a long-term release of Ubuntu.

File an issue to the Ubuntu 22.04 team to package and test a more recent version of the library, then wait until it makes it in the backports

Compile a newer version of the library yourself. Depending, it may be surprisingly easy, but also may be overly hard, to the point of unfeaible for the average user, if there are many dependencies.


